# Android Ndk Installation on windows?

Tags: android

I am going to use openGLES for 3d graphics. so i wat to install android NDK . can anyone help me to sort out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download [the ZIP file](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html). Install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) (1.7 or higher). Follow the instructions in the `INSTALL.TXT` file that is included in the ZIP file. Ask more specific questions on StackOverflow if there is something in `INSTALL.TXT` that you do not understand.

Comment: Since NDK-r7 (November 2011) Cygwin has not been mandatory on windows.

Comment: just to add to Habba's comment, you no longer need cygwin to run ndk-build, but still needs it to run ndk-gdb on Windows